# How to convert git log --pretty=format:%aN,%ae in a specific format?

Tags: bash, git, awk, sed, converters

I would like to convert `git log --pretty=format:%aN,%ae` in a specific format.

Orginal output of `git log --pretty=format:%aN,%ae`:

```
Yu-Cheng Ling,ycling@google.com
A. Unique TensorFlower,gardener@tensorflow.org
TensorFlower Gardener,gardener@tensorflow.org
A. Hugo Ronr,garer@yahoo.org
...more
```

The desired conversion should look as follows:

```
Yu-Cheng Ling,ycling@google.com, google
A. Unique TensorFlower,gardener@tensorflow.org, tensorflow
TensorFlower Gardener,gardener@tensorflow.org, tensorflow
A. Hugo Ronr,garer@yahoo.org, yahoo
...more
```

Any hints or tips? Or rather, how would you solve the problem?

Could someone please help me?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think git itself will help you extract the domain name, as it treats the email address as an opaque string, you'll have to do that yourself with something like `sed` or the text processing tool of your choice. Also keep in mind that there are valid domains such as `foo.example.org` and `example.co.uk`. You should know what you want to be extracted from those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data does not contains sub-domains something like this would work:

```
$ git log --pretty=format:%aN,%ae | sed -r 's/@(.+)(\..+)/@\1\2, \1/'

Yu-Cheng Ling,ycling@google.com, google
A. Unique TensorFlower,gardener@tensorflow.org, tensorflow
TensorFlower Gardener,gardener@tensorflow.org, tensorflow
```

If there are sub domains, the result would be:

```
TensorFlower Gardener,gardener@blog.tensorflow.net, blog.tensorflow
```